JUnit test error: java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.id" for 'andExpect'
So I am writing a Junit for a simple Post method controller. and I wrote the following Junit and it is   throwing an error:
I have the test here,
This is my Jnit code written: Does anything look wrong?
@Test
    public void testCreateCar() throws Exception {

      String custJson = "{\"name\": \"John Doe\", " +
                        "\"street\": \"123 Main St\", " +
                        "\"house_No\": \"45B\", " +
                        "\"place\": \"Springfield\", " +
                        "\"email\": \"john.doe@example.com\", " +
                        "\"ph_Number\": \"1234567890\"}";
      
      
    CustomerEntity customer = new CustomerEntity();
    customer.seters except ID...


    CustomerEntity customer2 = new CustomerEntity();
    customer2.setters.....

    given(custService.createCust(customer)).willReturn(customer2);
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/createCust")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(custJson))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id").value(1))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.name").value("John Doe"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.street").value("123 Main St"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.house_No").value("45B"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.place").value("Springfield"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.email").value("john.doe@example.com"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.ph_Number").value("1234567890"));
    }

Entity Class with GeneratedValue and ID
 @Entity
      public class CustomerEntity {

    public CustomerEntity(Integer id, String name, String street, String house_No, String place,
      @Email String email, @Pattern(regexp = "(^$|[0-9]{10})") String ph_Number) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.street = street;
    this.house_No = house_No;
    this.place = place;
    this.email = email;
    this.ph_Number = ph_Number;
    }

//constructor
    public CustomerEntity() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String house_No;
    private String place;
    @Email
    private String email;
    @Pattern(regexp = "(^$|[0-9]{10})")
    private String ph_Number;

Controller with endpoint:

    @PostMapping("/createCust")
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerEntity> createCust(@Valid @RequestBody CustomerEntity cust) {
    CustomerEntity customer = custService.createCust(cust);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(customer);
    }

This is my simple Service:
    public CustomerEntity createCust(CustomerEntity cust) {
    return custRepo.save(cust);
    }

What is wrong here with the test?
Error:
     java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.id"  at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:302) at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:99) at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.lambda$value$2(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:111) at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:214) at com.rupesh.assesment.carlease.controller.CustomerControllerTest.testCreateCar(CustomerControllerTest.java:57) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty  at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.Utils.notEmpty(Utils.java:401)  at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:390)  at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:377)  at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:299) ... 7 more


Your CustomerEntity is incomplete, make sure you have getters for the fields, without those Jackson cannot expose them as properties. I also suspect you haven't implemented a (proper) equals and hashCode method, which result in your mocks doing differnt things then you expect. It will probably return null instead of your customer. As you have a Customer created, your controller creates a new one, without a proper equals Mockito will not consider them equal.

@M.Deinum, I have geters and setters, just didn't mention it there.

@M.Deinum Thankssss. :)

Make sure you implement a proper equals and hashCode for use with JPA. See https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/hopefully-the-final-article-about-equals-and-hashcode-for-jpa-entities-with-db-generated-ids/

@M.Deinum I checked the link, Although I am facing same error for another class, even after generating equals() and hashcode()

Don't generate equals implement them as in the blog linked. The generated equals from your IDE are wrong for JPA. You can also use given(custService.createCust(any(Customer.class)).willReturn(customer2); which will basically always return customer2. Nonetheless you would still need and benefit from a proper equals (in this case it wouldn't work as it always returns false for a null id).

The reason is that your controller is annotated with @Controller. You must use @RestController annotation to make your controller return JSON.

Assumptions, you would need to see the full controller (and it is unlikely that that is the actual error).
